# Openx Android layout issue

Tags: android, ads, openx

I am attempting to display OpenX ads within an Android application. I have installed the SDK and followed the video found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z7BdjLnb7s&feature=youtu.be). Everything is going smoothly, except when I edit the layout. I am constantly greeted with this friendly error message in the error log.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Thu Mar 14 17:40:44 PDT 2013
com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner failed to instantiate.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.controllers.OXMAdBaseController.<init>(OXMAdBaseController.java:130)
    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.controllers.OXMAdController.<init>(OXMAdController.java:37)
    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.init(OXMAdBanner.java:141)
    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.reflectAttrs(OXMAdBanner.java:136)
    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.<init>(OXMAdBanner.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I can't find any help on Google, and I am wondering if anyone has had this issue before. I have my manifest set up properly, and am running android:targetSdkVersion="17"

```
<activity
android:name="com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.OXMAdBrowser"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

So since there are no build errors, I am able to launch my app, but it quickly creahses and throws some errors.

```
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.portlandtribune.pamplinmedia_beta/com.portlandtribune.pamplinmedia_beta.PM_section}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.portlandtribune.pamplinmedia_beta.PM_section.onCreate(PM_section.java:145)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    ... 11 more
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    ... 24 more
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.controllers.OXMAdBaseController.<init>(OXMAdBaseController.java:161)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.controllers.OXMAdController.<init>(OXMAdController.java:37)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.init(OXMAdBanner.java:141)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.reflectAttrs(OXMAdBanner.java:136)
03-14 17:45:35.517: E/AndroidRuntime(23227):    at com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner.<init>(OXMAdBanner.java:86)
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Other information

I am using the standard code for the xml layout file. I know I haven't specified any details but it shouldn't be returning a com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner failed to instantiate error. Right?

```
<com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    domain="d.example.com"
    portrait_id="1234"
    landscape_id="4321"
    change_interval="30000" />
```

Comment: Did you add the methods and the prepare call inside onCreate? It means it around 2:20 in the video. If still cant get it working, please also post relevant part of your activity code.

Comment: I have edited the main post. I hope that helps. The id's and domain are not filled in, but it throws the error on build.

Comment: From where you got portrait_id and landscape_id? And domain url too? I have my own server where revive ad server is installed. How to get these values? If you know please help me to solve my problem.